# How to install flannel in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, flannel

I follow the instrument from flannel on git
Step 1: Make sure you have required dependencies installed on your machine. On Ubuntu, run `sudo apt-get install linux-libc-dev golang gcc`. On Fedora/Redhat, `run sudo yum install kernel-headers golang gcc`.
Step 2: Git clone the flannel repo: git clone https://github.com/coreos/flannel.git
Step 3: Run the build script: cd flannel; `./build`

But after I clone the source code in my disk, I can not find `build.sh` in flannel folder. How can I run ./build?

Comment: This is duplicating on github
https://github.com/coreos/flannel/issues/480

Answer (score 2):

The documentation is out-of-date.  Just call `make`.
Another thing you can try, is to look at the successful log from the [continuous integration](https://travis-ci.org/coreos/flannel).
Follow the necessary steps that have been shown to work.